# Is it possible to host PHP project to sharepoint?

Tags: deployment, php

I just developed a PHP project by using localhost (XAMPP). I would like to ask whether it is possible to deploy or to host my web project to Sharepoint. If it is possible, can anyone share me how it can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cant host the PHP in SharePoint but what you can, Host the PHP sites on the Same server using Host header in IIS.

Then you can use the BCS or write a code to bring that project/data into SharePoint.

[Read this to understand](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/90694c90-6aff-4c50-b584-beb09d6a3d56/can-be-install-php-on-sharepoint-server-2010?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545824/how-to-connect-sharepoint-with-php